# Statistical significance for difference in mean proportions when comparing groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data, contingency-tables

I may not have described my problem precisely, but I hope I can illustrate it with the following example.

Suppose that I have $m$ contingency tables:

|  | Col 1 | Col 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | $a_i$ | $b_i$ | $a_i+b_i$ |
| Row 2 | $c_i$ | $d_i$ | $c_i+d_i$ |
| Total | $a_i+c_i$ | $b_i+d_i$ | $N$ |

where $a_i+b_i+c_i+d_i=N,i=1,2,\dots,m$. For each table, let $p_{1i}=\frac{a_i+b_i}{N}, p_{2i}=\frac{a_i+c_i}{N}$, the standard error of $p_{1i}-p_{2i}$ is given by
$$se(p_{1i}-p_{2i})=\frac{1}{N}\sqrt{b_i+c_i-\frac{(b_i-c_i)^2}{N}}.$$
Since
$$
Var\left({{p_{1i}}-p_{2i}}\right)={Var(p_{1i})+Var(p_{2i})}- {2Cov(p_{1i},p_{2j})}=\frac{1}{N^2}\left(b_i+c_i-\frac{(b_i-c_i)^2}{N}\right).
$$
Then I can perform a significance test of the null hypothesis that $p_{1i}=p_{2i}$, on the assumption that the null hypothesis is true, the standard error simplifies to
$$
se(p_{1i}-p_{2i})=\frac{1}{N}\sqrt{b_i+c_i},
$$

and the test statistic is
$$
z=\frac{p_{1i}-p_{2i}}{se(p_{1i}-p_{2i})}=\frac{b_i-c_i}{\sqrt{b_i+c_i}}.
$$
**My question**

How to perform the following test?
$$H_0:\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{1i}}}{m}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{2i}}}{m}$$
$$H_1:\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{1i}}}{m}\not=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{2i}}}{m}$$
In fact, ach pair of $(p_{is},p_{jt}) $ is dependent, $i,j\in\{1,2\}, 1\le s,t \le m$, and I can also obtain all contingency tables corresponding to each pair. Similarly, I can calculate the standard error of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{1i}}-p_{2i}}{m}$ after determining their covariance matrix,
$$
Var\left({\sum_{i=1}^m{p_{1i}}-p_{2i}}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m \left({Var(p_{1i})+Var(p_{2i})}\right)+{2\sum_{1\le i< j \le m}\left({Cov(p_{1i},p_{1j})+Cov(p_{2i},p_{2j})}\right)} - {2\sum_{1\le i \le j \le m}{Cov(p_{1i},p_{2j})}}
$$
How can I simpliefies it on the assumption that the null hypothesis is true. Can I use it directly ignoring the condition that ${\sum_{i=1}^m{b_{i}}}={\sum_{i=1}^m{c_{i}}}$.

Any other testing method or articles/books related to my problem are ok. Thanks in advance！

Comment: Do I understand well that you are looking for a common risk difference in a stratified sample? Quite a few methods exist, Mantel-Haenszel (1959) being the original & Miettinen-Nurminen (1985) a personal favourite, although they assume independence ($Cov(p_1,p_2)=0$) and homogeneity of risk.

Comment: @PBulls Thanks for your reply！In my original question, there were $m$ models that performed two-category predictions. Each contingency table here represents the prediction results (true or false) of models before and after improvement. I want to test whether this improvement is statistically significant among all models. I will read the references you provided.